# Can I run my laptop directly from an external battery at full throttle while charging my iPhone from the laptop at the same time?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, usb, battery, power

I would like the freedom to power my laptop from an external battery to avoid very frequent cycling between 100% and 90% (say 2 or 3 times a day) due to my unique work/travel habits.

I've never bought an external battery large enough for a laptop; so I have no experience using them. Googling finds plenty of material on units that can *recharge* a laptop, but I am not sure if they recharge a laptop running at full power, say doing a numerical calculation while watching YouTube via USB hotlinking to 4G with my iPhone which is also being recharged via USB.

Of course the above scenario is the worst case, but it could conceivably happen on a long train ride after a busy day.

I am often moving around a lot and even on public transportation and simply can not plug in to mains power as frequently as I would like.

- MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2020)
- 1.1 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
- Intel Iris Plus Graphics 1536 MB
- macOS 10.15.7
- iPhone SE-2

Comment: Sounds like you need to test it for yourself.

Comment: @SolarMike No, it does not sound like that. Are you certain nobody in this community can answer nor can can anyone find one? I think there is enough information out there to formulate a reasonable answer, especially if the answer turns out to be “no” or “I do this and it works”. Your comment seems spurious, uninformed and unhelpful to me, what is the value in posting it?

Comment: I would use a small powerbank to charge the phone ( have 4 btw). That reduces the load on the mac. My powerbooks can easily charge my phone - but it is only a 6S plus and I don’t do charging of the phone. The only time the phone gets connected by cable is to back up.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm poor. To solve my problem I've started with the lowest cost path; ask if it is likely to work or not here before buying a big battery just to try it. And if I can get away with one big battery I don't want to spend even more money and increase the weight in my backpack further by buying a second, redundant battery. It's also bad for the environment to buy batteries we don't need just for the heck of it. Let's wait for some fact-based answers.

Comment: There are so many external battery packs with different specs, and your use case is very specific, that I think it'll be hard to come up with something usable for your situation. I'd consider an external power source which can charge both your laptop and iPhone independently, without the need to have the phone plugged into the laptop to charge. You really need to read about laptop batteries [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201585) and [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204054) to help you figure out if what you intend to do is actually _good for the battery's health._

Comment: This is a good example why hardware shopping is off topic here. I’m going to vote to close this. Nothing about this is unique to an apple phone or apple portable. Would the answer change materially if the phone were android and the portable a dell that used USB PD?

Comment: @bmike Shopping is never mentioned in my question!  I've only powered my laptop using a wall plug, I have no experience using a battery. I know that Apple products often use communication protocols with the device connected to the USB port, even devices that provide power. It's possible that my Apple computer would say "no, that's a battery, not an Apple/compatible wall plug converter" and not accept it as a power source, or only when the computer is sleeping in order to charge at a lower rate.

Comment: The goal here is to find out if that is likely to happen before I invest in a battery large enough to run a laptop. I've asked almost 5,000 Stack Exchange questions, and I've gotten pretty good at thinking things through before asking them and I absolutely do not ask shopping questions. This question seems rational and clear just like the rest. I've asked for a fact-based answer to "Will X work? I understand some of the users here feel this is an advice column and prefers the "please tell me what to do?" type questions, but it should also be able to support "Will X work" questions as well, no?

Comment: @bmike "Would the answer change materially if the phone were android and the portable a dell that used USB PD?" *Yes of course!* Surely you know how closed the Apple ecosystem is compared to Android. There is absolutely no expectation that MacBook is going to work just like an Android or DELL product. I am stymied to understand how you can think that they would be the same!

Comment: @bmike My question reads "Can I run my laptop directly from an external battery at full throttle while charging my iPhone from the laptop at the same time?" and you call it a shopping question? How do you get shopping from that?

Comment: @bmike I've just asked [In what way did a moderator decide my "Would X work? question is a "shopping question"? I think this has been mishandled, what do others think?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4066/143729)

Comment: There are tons of external batteries on the market, most of them actually have more than one port so you could also just charge both the Macbook and the iPhone directly from the battery. Hard to say how many mAh you'll need though (I usually go with "more is better").

Comment: @nohillside okay, but while I understand that I can *recharge my laptop* with said batteries, I still don't know if I can run the laptop "full throttle" at the same time; there could be some non-power limit related reason that it might not work. I've looked but so far not found anything definitive on this. About plugging the phone into the battery, my question states that I want to access 4G hotspot through the USB by plugging it into the laptop. Would routing it the way you describe still give me hotspot via USB?

Comment: You would need to enable the WiFi hotspot on your phone then (which of course needs more power). But ok, if you want to use the hotspot via USB, then plug it into the MB :-)

Comment: Okay I am getting the distinct impression that the answer may be "Yes" though nobody has yet said so explicitly either way. In most SE sites someone will come around and go ahead and post an answer to that effect, I would then accept the answer, and all would be well. I'm allergic to answers in comments, so hopefully someone will here.

Comment: So, 12V battery, 24V battery, 48V battery or 96 V battery? then will you be using an inverter to provide mains (230V Ac or 110V AC) to the "standard" charger or will you provide Dc directly to the mac?

Comment: @solarmike Let’s assume the OP is talking about powerbanks here :-)

Answer (score 1):

What will tell you if a power bank is capable of charging your laptop under load is how much power it can provide vs. power the laptop consumes.  How do you know how much power your laptop consumes?  The size of the power supply that came with the laptop should give some idea as Apple will size the power supply to the power demands of the laptop.

How can you know how much power a power bank can provide?  You will have to look closely at the specifications.  If you are lucky then the manufacturer will spell that out clearly for you.  If you can't find that spelled out for you then you can do some math on the specs you can find.  Volts times amps equals watts.  If you can find volts and amps then you can get power.

It also helps to keep in mind the USB-C specs on power delivery as that will at least provide a sanity check on the numbers you get.  USB Power Delivery 3.0 is limited to 100 watts, 20 volts at 5 amps, so most power banks will not exceed that.  USB Power Delivery 3.1 is still quite new but if you do happen to find a power bank that meets this spec then it is possible to see the power bank supply up to 240 watts.

Another rule to keep in mind about USB Power Deliver is that it does not allow for more current than 5 amps.  If some power and voltage combination adds up to more than 5 amps then check your numbers, there's likely an error somewhere.

Given the growth in power consumption of laptops lately it is quite possible you won't find a power bank that is powerful enough for your needs, the market just hasn't had enough time to catch up.  Good luck though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So *in principle* my MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2020) will happily run from a battery as long as it can deliver sufficient power and perhaps is recognized by Apple as a suitable product? The laptop queries each USB device connected, including power sources, and it will know that it's a battery and not a wall plug converter. I just want to confirm that my laptop won't say "No thank you, I can charge from you while asleep but I won't accept power from you right now because I'm doing a critical task" or similar.

Comment: I don't know if an Apple laptop knows or cares if the supply that is plugged is a battery or supply connected to mains.  USB-PD has a means to negotiate voltage and keep current draw within certain bounds.  As far as I know Apple laptops will not change their behavior on drawing power based on being powered up, asleep, or powered off.  Whether the laptop charges or not is dependent on if the power in is greater than power consumed.  Even if a power bank cannot provide enough power to charge it can still extend use time by lowering rate of power drawn from the internal battery.

Comment: I see, as long as they can negotiate successfully, perhaps "batteryness" is a non-issue.